# how to simply join two collections into one and remove dupulication in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I only need to join two collections together without merge or combine with any objects.

For example, I have two collections with the same structures.

From **Collection A**

```
{"Id": 12345678, "name" : "Em", "text" : "MongoDB is hard to learn"}
{"Id": 1234, "name" : "Fm", "text" : "MongoDB is fun"}
```

From **Collection B**

```
{"Id": 12345678, "name" : "Em", "text" : "MongoDB is hard to learn"}
{"Id": 678, "name" : "Gm", "text" : "MongoDB is ok"}
```

All I need is to bring collection A and Collection B to collection C and remove the duplication (which is `Id"123345678"`).

**Collection C** should be

```
{"Id": 12345678, "name" : "Em", "text" : "MongoDB is hard to learn"}
{"Id": 1234, "name" : "Fm", "text" : "MongoDB is fun"}
{"Id": 678, "name" : "Gm", "text" : "MongoDB is ok"}
```

I searched a lot but people usually want to involve object using `$lookup` which I don't need to involve any o jects. I just hope two collections become one and without duplications.

Thank you